# Python and class attribute declarations

Tags: python, class, attributes, pep8

I have been told that declaring dynamic attributes within a classes scope is not the 'Python Way' but I do not understand why.
Could someone explain this to me or point me at some documentation as to why this is a bad thing? Honestly, I thought this was good practice, if anything for self documenting code.

Example:

```
class ClassA(object):
    user_data = {}

    def set_user(self):
        self.user_data['username'] = 'fred'
```

The only reason I can see for not using this is that attributes are static (and so could be misleading)..

Comment: You should access either with self.user_data or with ClassA.user_data

Comment: It's nothing to do with it being pythonic or not. It's to do with the fact that `user_data` is shared among all instances of the class. It's a class attribute. And most developers expect it to be an instance attribute instead, leading to strange behaviour (to them).

Comment: fixed.. sorry was a typo

Comment: @MartijnPieters - i understand that its basically a static attribute but the data doesn't cross between instances, so i don't see a problem. Fair enough though, i understand your point.. thanks.

Comment: In python terminology, we talk about 'class attributes' and 'mutable values' instead of 'static' and 'dynamic attributes'. But if your *intention* is for the data to be shared among classes, then this is a perfectly fine way to do it. Nothing un-pythonic about it.

Comment: Well each instance with have different mutable user_data.. I would only declare it for documentation/readability... So i am wrong.  Thanks Martijn :) Bringing PHP habits with me.

Comment: @Lee: the way your code is written, there is only one user_data dict shared by all instances of ClassA.  I'm not sure that's been made clear enough yet.  The code will not work as you want.  It isn't a style issue.

Comment: Thanks Ned, just tested this again.. and it didn't work.. Data was shared between the instances.. Now i understand.. thanks

Comment: @Lee: maybe select an answer as the correct one? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code as shown, `user_data` isn't a *dynamic attribute* (It's not created on the class instance "dynamically").  It's a *class attribute* which is a lot more like "static" attributes in some other languages I believe.  This means that it is an attribute declared on the class at the time the class is read and initialized.  This has the side-effect/benefit of all of the instances being able to access the same object via `self.whatever`.

In other words:

```
class Foo(object):
    whatever = {}
    def __init__(self):
        print self.whatever is Foo.whatever
```

will always print `True`.  Of course, you can change this behavior by adding a different `whatever` attribute to an instance:

```
class Bar(object):
     whatever = {}
     def __init__(self):
         self.whatever = {}
         print self.whatever is Bar.whatever
```

With `Foo`, if I add items: `foo_instance.whatever['foo'] = 'bar'`, then `foo_instance2` will see that change as well, whereas that won't be the case with `Bar`.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, you say, "Well each instance will have different mutable user_data."  No, it will not. Every instance of ClassA will share the same user_data dictionary:

```
>>> class ClassA(object):
...     user_data = {}
...     def set_user(self, name):
...         self.user_data['name'] = name
...
>>> a1 = ClassA()
>>> a1.set_user('fred')
>>> a1.user_data
{'name': 'fred'}
>>>
>>> a2 = ClassA()
>>> a2.user_data
{'name': 'fred'}
>>> a2.set_user('barney')
>>> a2.user_data
{'name': 'barney'}
>>>
>>> a1.user_data
{'name': 'barney'}
>>>
>>> a1.user_data is a2.user_data
True
```

This isn't a matter of whether something is Pythonic or not.  It's a matter of writing code that behaves as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I've marked another answer as the correct one as it helps other people a little more.. but thanks :) you made me realise the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using class and instance members:

```
class Test(object):
    instances = {}

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.instance = self
        self.instances[name] = self

    # rest of class

a = Test('alfred')
b = Test('banana')

# use a to get a
print a.instance

>>> 
<__main__.Test object at 0x0000000002BEBC50>

# get all instances of the Test class
print Test.instances

>>>
{'banana': <__main__.Test object at 0x0000000002BEBDA0>, 'alfred': <__main__.Test object at 0x0000000002BEBC50>}
```

As these are just examples, they do not reflect anything specific, just what can be done.

Declaring a class member is useful in some situations, like above if you want to be able to document, and control all of the types of a certain class. But you should always understand what it is you are doing, and don't think that `instance` is local to each instance.

As to the question of 'best practice' and 'most pythonic way'. It is just that, opinions. Some things will be frowned upon by some people, and not by others. You should write in a way that makes you comfortable, and that works for you, as long as you conform to the regulations and standards imposed by any workforce you happen to be a part of.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, class attributes are probably different than you expect.

Example:

```
class Example(object):
    class_data={}
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.val) 

>>> Example.class_data['one']=1    # assign value to the empty dict in class Example
>>> e1,e2=Example(1), Example(2)   # INSTANCES-self.val different for each instance
>>> print e1,e2,e1.class_data,e2.class_data
1 2 {'one': 1} {'one': 1}
      ^^^^^      ^^^^^         # SAME class_data in two different instances
```

Note that *each* instance of Example has the same mutable copy of class_data. It is not protected as a static class variable would be in Java or C++.

Indeed, you can change, add or delete these class attributes at will at any time:

```
>>> Example.class_data='old dict is gone gone gone...'
>>> print e1,e2,e1.class_data,e2.class_data  
1 2 old dict is gone gone gone... old dict is gone gone gone...
```

You may see code like this:

```
class Example(object):
    class_constants=('fee','fie','foe')
    # ...
```

With the false comfort that it is acting like constant (in another language) because of this:

```
>>> e1=Example(1)
>>> e1.class_constants[4]='fum'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

But this is a false comfort because a piece of code can always do this:

```
>>> Example.class_constants=('another','tuple','of','constants')
```

The trouble that some have with class attributes is that they are not doing what is expected -- as if it is a constant. They are not constants. Class attributes change the data for the all existing and future instances of the class. Useful sometimes, but potentially confusing.

It does not matter, really, if the class attribute is mutable or not. As you see -- you can change the attribute at any time.